# Printing prime numbers up to n

Tags: c, numbers

I have written some code to ask the user for n, then print the prime numbers up to n. However when I use it, i.e with 10, it only prints the non-prime numbers

```
 /* Asks for the amount of prime numbers you would like to print, then prints them */

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n, i, j, check;
    printf("How many prime numbers would you like to print? ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        check = 0;

        for (j = 2; j < i ; j++) { 
            if (i % j == 0) {
                check = 1;              
                if (check == 1) {
                    printf("%d\n", i);
                }
            }
        }
    }       

    return 0;
}

How many prime numbers would you like to print? 10
4
6
6
8
8
9
10
10
```

I've tried everything but I think I am missing something really trivial!

Comment: `if (i % j == 0)` means there was no remainder, that is, it's not prime. If your output sense was reversed, that's a strong hint to look at your comparisons.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: @Barmar so many people divide by `1` and `n` and then check for more divisors than 2! Oops that's an exclamation, not a factorial, although in this case they are the same.

Comment: It's kind of useless to put `if (check == 1)` right after `check = 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it should be:

```
for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
{
    check = 0;

    for (j = 2; j < i ; j++)
    {

        if (i % j == 0)
        {
            check = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (check == 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

Also, in the inner loop you don't have to divide the number till `j < i`. You don't have to go beyond `i/2`.

Comment: Actually, beyond `sqrt(i)`

Answer (score 1):

As Weather Vane said, the mod operator `%` returns 0 if `i` is exactly divisible by `j` and if this is true then the number is **not** prime. Your conditional statement is backwards.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   int n, i, j, check;
   printf("How many prime numbers would you like to print? ");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) 
   {
       check = 0;
       for (j = 2; j < i ; j++) 
       { 
           if (i % j == 0) 
           {
               check = 1;
               break;
           }
       }
       if (check == 0)
       {
           printf("%d\n", i);
       }
   }

   return 0;
}

How many prime numbers would you like to print? 10
2
3
5
7
```

Answer (score 1):

Several problems.

First, when you set `check = 1`, that means that `i` divides evenly, so `n` is **not** prime, so you shouldn't print it. You should be printing the number when `check == 0`.

Second, you're printing each time through the inner loop. You should test `check` at the end of the loop, to ensure that none of the numbers divided it.

As an improvement, there's no need to keep checking once you find one number that divides evenly. So you can break out of the inner loop as soon as you set `check = 1`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n, i, j, check;
    printf("How many prime numbers would you like to print? ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        check = 0;

        for (j = 2; j < i ; j++) { 
            if (i % j == 0) {
                check = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (check == 0) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }       

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try looking at this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int IsPrime(int num)
{
    int i = 2;

    for (i = 2; i < num; i++) if (num % i == 0) return 0;

    return 1;
}

int main(void)

{
    int n, i;
    char *nStr = (char*)malloc(10);

    printf("How many prime numbers would you like to print? ");
    fgets(nStr, 9, stdin);
    n = atoi(nStr);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) if (IsPrime(i)) printf("%d\n", i);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

and about your code, you should print the number only if check remains 0.

Comment: `free(nStr)`? Was the `malloc` a bit of overkill for an `int` input? And you could have used a loop `for (i = 2; i < n; i++)` since every number is divisible by 1 and itself.